# Secure Android to Online Database connection

Tags: android

I am working on an Android project where I will have to edit (only decrement) data from an online database. I want to stop anybody from changing the values by themselves. It should be possible only through the Programming.

In short my online database would contain the Balance of a particular account.
While using some of my services in my app, the balance will get deducted.
App should only be able to deduct the value. I dont want any hacker to study my code and be able to increment the balance by any mean.

Is there any possible mean to add security to database. The database should be very secure.

Answer (score 0):

If you want security over network, Do it using existing and well implemented secure protocol, e.g. TLS/SSL. openssl is one good implementation: http://www.openssl.org/

If you even want data to be secure on the server, even the root cannot access it, check this: http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/